# Scilab "Invalid index" when calling for a value in a matrix with a variable

Tags: excel, scilab

I am somehow new in Scilab, but I have a problem, that I cannot figure out why it is happening.

I am "translating" a code that is originally in Excel to Scilab, but when I create something like xlookup function,

Here is the part of the code

```
//Import Power Curve from Excel
function [K,Kx,Ky] = ImportExcel(sheetname,sheetnumber);
    mode(0)
    sheets = readxls(sheetname);
    s1 = sheets(sheetnumber);
    s1 = s1.value;     //Values as values
    a = size(s1,"r");   //determining the size for separate tables
    b = size(s1,"c");

    Kx = s1(10,2:b);   //Creation of 3 lists
    Ky = s1(11:a,1);
    K  = s1(11:a,2:b);
endfunction

function [k] = xlookup(target,Searched,r,c,direction, exact)
    //target    - Value searched
    //Searched  - Table to be searched
    //r         - line (row) to be searched
    //c         - columnn to be seached
    //direction - if "h"orizontal or "v"ertical
    //exact     - 0 Exact, 1 Up, -1 Down

    mode(0)
    i=0;
    j=0;

    if direction == "h" then
        for j = 1 : size(Searched , 'c')
            delta(r,j) = abs( target - Searched(r,j) );
        end

        if exact == -1; //down
            k = find(delta == min(delta)) - 1;
        elseif exact == 0; //exact
            k = find(delta == min(delta));            
        elseif exact == 1 //up
            k = find(delta == min(delta)) + 1; 
        end

    elseif direction == "v" then
        for i = 1 : size(Searched , 'r')
            delta(i,c) = abs( target - Searched(i,c) );
        end

        if exact == -1; //down
            k = find(delta == min(delta)) - 1;
        elseif exact == 0; //exact
            k = find(delta == min(delta));            
        elseif exact == 1 //up
            k = find(delta == min(delta)) + 1; 
        end
    end
endfunction

//vertical interpolation
function VI = vinterpol(Target_vi,Searched_vi,r,c,direction,exact)
    VI = zeros(size(Target_vi,'r'),1);
    for i = 1:size(Target_vi, 'r')
        tt = Target_vi(i,c);
        ii = xlookup(tt,Searched_vi,r,c,direction,exact);
        VI(i,c) = Searched_vi(ii,c);
    end
endfunction


//Taking the Headers and Values of the PowerCurve
[K,Kx,Ky] = ImportExcel('WDS_315 PowerCurves.xls',3);

TestW_minus1 = vinterpol(W_WS, Ky,1,1,"v",-1)
```

The problem is alway with this code

```
VI(i,c) = Searched_vi(ii,c);
```

The function xlookup works fine for me. The output is the position in the vector where the vinterpol will apply the result. I suppose there is other way to create a new vector based on results inside a for. Thank you for all the help.

I tried using different names, apply with other vectors. In fact, when I use a small generated vector, it works, but when I work with Excel vectors, the problem repeats.

Comment: It’s hard to know what’s going on without knowing what your vectors look like coming out of Excel. Can you take a look at them, see what is different between the Ky vector coming out of ImportExcel and your small generated vectors, and try to include those in your question? Also, once you do, you may be able to produce the error just with vinterpol and can remove  ImportExcel from your question. See [mre].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes. When I tried to replicate what comes from excel, I've noticed that there is 0, inside Excel values, and was not in my test. The excel file has 65000 rows. For that reason I didn't paste here. When I work with 0, xlookup returns 0, and this is not an index. The solution for me was to add an IF inside the FOR, separating whatever result <=0. Thank you.

Comment: You should explain better what you want to do and we could help to improve your code. For example your loops can be vectorized and the index of the min or max value is yielded as second output argument of `min()` and `max()`. And providing a small subset of the xls file could help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `xlookup` function can be simplified like this:

```
function [k] = xlookup(target,Searched,r,c,direction, exact)
    //target    - Value searched
    //Searched  - Table to be searched
    //r         - line (row) to be searched
    //c         - columnn to be seached
    //direction - if "h"orizontal or "v"ertical
    //exact     - 0 Exact, 1 Up, -1 Down

    if direction == "h" then
        [value,k] = min(abs(target - Searched(r,:)));
    elseif direction == "v" then
        [value,k] = min(abs(target - Searched(:,c)));
    end
    k = k + exact;
endfunction
```

This function yields `0` when `k==1` and `exact==-1`. Indices of matrices start at 1 in Scilab, this explains the error you get when you use its result as `ii` in `Searched_vi(ii,c)`.